# Secure Copy (scp) between two Linux servers using a Win10 OpenSSH as proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, proxy

**The design:** multiple network security zones, some with Linux servers only, some with Windows only.

**Objective:** Secure Copy (`scp`) between two Linux servers using a Win10 OpenSSH  as proxy

```
linux1 (zone A) > Win10-1 (zone B) > linux2 (zone C)
```

[Updated: some progress] Authentication is SSH key based. I ran ssh-keygen on `linux1`and copied the .pub file to `Win10-1`, then copied the content into `C:\Users\[username]\.ssh\authorized_keys` and this works as intended: I can ssh from `linux1` into the `Win10-1`passwordless.
The same procedure *should* work when running `ssh-keygen` on `Win10-1`; I have my key pair and copy the pub file to `linux2` but logging in from `Win10-1`to `linux2` using `ssh user@linux2` fails and the Powershell prompt hangs - but if I do `Start ssh user@linux2`, then it works.

To test the intended connection, I did:

```
#linux1: ssh -J username@proxy-win10 username@target-linux2
```

And it gets me through just fine - but only after prompting for the login password on `linux2`.

I suspect that the final hurdle is that required `Start ssh user@linux2` - is the OpenSSH server instance maybe broken?

Comment: Were you prompted for password for the private key or for the login password?

Comment: @DannyNiu login pw

Comment: Are you able to go on Win10 machine and run `ssh -vvv username@target-linux2` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually mostly a security question.

## Point 1

The only way an SSH proxy can be useful is when the target host stays behind public network, such as the following:

```
                                     +--- Office Computer 1
Internet <--- Router-NAT-Firewall <--+--- Office Computer 2
                                     +--- Linux Server (no port forwarding)
                                     +=== Windows Server (with SSH port forwarding)
```

Otherwise, your Windows server is just an actor playing in a security theater.

## Point 2

SSH is a very useful transport protocol for applications, you should maximize its security by mandating users use public-key cryptography to authenticate themselves.

In "sshd_config":

- Use the "AllowUsers" directive to select the users allowed to login from SSH.
- Use the "Match" directive on the selected users and use "AuthenticationMethods" directive to restrict them from logging in with passwords.

Comment: No problem security-wise - and that was not my question. The design is what it is; what I have to deal with is getting the key authentication to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: That'd be my point 2 in the answer - configure the server to deny less-secure user-authentication methods.